# How to add search column?

Tags: search, yii2

I managed to combine two columns. But the searching column is missing. How to add searching column?
Here is the code :

```
echo GridView::widget([
                        'dataProvider' => $dataProviderAcad,
                        'filterModel' => $searchModelAcad,
                        'columns' => [
                            'prog_and_remark_combined' => [
                                'format' => 'raw',
                                'label' => "Programme Name",
                                'value' => function ($data) {
                                    return nl2br(
                                        $data->NAME_PROG_ENG .
                                        "\r\nPreviously known as: " .
                                        $data->REMARKS
                                    );
                                }
                            ],
```

Comment: add `'attribute' => 'columnName'` which you will be use for search.

Comment: You need to edit the search model.  You need to add the custom field at the top of the class like this public $prog_and_remark_combined;  You then need to add it into your rules and lastly you need to add code in to do the search of the new concatenated field.

Answer (score 0):

In you Class for AcadSearch  add  a pubblic  var for prog_and_remark_combined

```
    class YourModelAcadSearch extends YourModelAcad
    {

        public $prog_and_remark_combined;

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
            ....
```